# Swift 3: cut a hole in a SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skcropnode

First of all: I know, that this questions has already many answers here, but they didn't helped me to solve this this problem.

I program a little game. At the first launch there is a little tutorial, where bit by bit each element of the game is explained. In each step I want to highlight one of these elements. So I put a black SKSpriteNode with an alpha of 0.9 in front of the elements. If an element should be highlighted, the SpriteNode should become transparent at this point. So I made an SKCropNode and a mask as shown in my code below (I just show you the essential parts):

```
import SpriteKit

class FirstLaunch: SKScene {

    var fullScreen:SKSpriteNode!
    var mask:SKSpriteNode!
    var circle1:SKShapeNode!
    var circle2:SKShapeNode!
    var crop:SKCropNode!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        fullScreen = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: self.size)
        fullScreen.anchorPoint = .zero
        fullScreen.position = .zero
        fullScreen.alpha = 0.9

        mask = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: self.size)
        mask.anchorPoint = .zero
        mask.position = .zero
        mask.alpha = 1

        circle1 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 55)
        circle1.fillColor = .white
        circle1.lineWidth = 0
        circle1.alpha = 1
        circle1.blendMode = .subtract

        //spaceship is one of my elements, which have to be highlighted at some point
        circle1.position = spaceship.position
        mask.addChild(circle1)

        //At one point I need two highlights at the same time
        circle2 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 55)
        circle2.fillColor = .white
        circle2.lineWidth = 0
        circle2.alpha = 1
        circle2.blendMode = .subtract

        crop = SKCropNode()
        crop.maskNode = mask
        crop.addChild(fullScreen)

        addChild(crop)
    }
}
```

I found this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40710050/8162321
I tested it on different devices and simulators. My problem is, that it works perfect in the simulators of both Xcode 8 and Xcode 9 Beta, but neither on an iPhone with iOS 10.3.3 nor on an iPhone with iOS 11 Beta. On the iPhones the whole app worked perfectly except of the highlight point.

Images:

[One tutorial-point on the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zeMZ.png)

[The same on the iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC8ew.png)

Can you tell me why it is different? I never seen something like that before.

Comment: You are going to need to explain yourself better, maybe provide some images

Comment: I am not following why you are setting the anchor point to zero

Comment: KnightOfDragon I added some images

Comment: If I don't set the anchor point and the position to zero, the fullscreen SKSpriteNode won't cover the whole screen

Comment: Well that is going to cause you problems,  the anchor points need to be at 0.5,0.5 to properly align  everything

Comment: Your scene also has to be 0.5,0.5

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why and how set the scene to 0.5,0.5

Comment: because that sets your origin to the center of the screen, which means everything aligns to the center.  Right now you are mixing center alignment with bottom left alignment, and since everything is not aligned, you are not getting the results you are expecting to see

Comment: That can't be the problem, because it works perfectly in the simulator

Comment: if it works in the simulator and not on your device then it means you are using 2 different iOS versions, and the default behavior is different

Comment: I am going to guess on the simulator that you are using the newest iOS available, which means the default anchor point is 0.5,0.5,  your phone is probably defaulting to 0,0

Comment: the other problem may be z order  give your overlay a higher z order

Comment: Comparing my code to yours, I do 2 things different. I leave the anchorPoint for mask alone, and  I set the zPosition of the mask higher

Comment: Can you post your code here, that I can see what you changed?

Comment: I didnt change anything, I am looking at the code you linked to

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problems. It tooks me 3 weeks to find out.

Set the aplha of the hole to 0.001 and the blendmode to .replace.
Then it will work on device (for me on iOS 12).

```
import SpriteKit

class FirstLaunch: SKScene {

    var fullScreen:SKSpriteNode!
    var mask:SKSpriteNode!
    var circle1:SKShapeNode!
    var circle2:SKShapeNode!
    var crop:SKCropNode!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        fullScreen = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: self.size)
        fullScreen.anchorPoint = .zero
        fullScreen.position = .zero
        fullScreen.alpha = 0.9

        mask = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: self.size)
        mask.anchorPoint = .zero
        mask.position = .zero
        mask.alpha = 1

        circle1 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 55)
        circle1.fillColor = .white
        circle1.lineWidth = 0

        // Here is the required change
        circle1.alpha = 0.001
        circle1.blendMode = .replace

        //spaceship is one of my elements, which have to be highlighted at some point
        circle1.position = spaceship.position
        mask.addChild(circle1)

        crop = SKCropNode()
        crop.maskNode = mask
        crop.addChild(fullScreen)

        addChild(crop)
    }
}
```

Comment: Awsome. thanks! I've spent several hours to find this solution