# How to making a spotlight effect with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Before I ask this question, I have double checked the following questions and examples:

1. [SKCropNode not working on device while working on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574534/skcropnode-not-working-on-device-while-working-on-simulator)
2. [Swift 3: cut a hole in a SKSpriteNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406414/swift-3-cut-a-hole-in-a-skspritenode/47575193#47575193)

The above works well on all simulators, however, it doesn't work on real device.

My Code in ObjetiveC:

```
SKSpriteNode* mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:size];
mask.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
mask.name = @"Mask";
mask.alpha = 0.5;
mask.zPosition = 3;

SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:size];
node.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
node.name = @"circleMask";
node.zPosition = 1;
node.alpha = 1;
SKShapeNode* circleNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:100/2+20];
circleNode.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
circleNode.lineWidth = 0;
circleNode.alpha = 1;
circleNode.position = CGPointMake(80, -200);
circleNode.name = @"circleNode";
circleNode.zPosition = 1;
circleNode.blendMode = SKBlendModeSubtract;
[node addChild:circleNode];

SKCropNode* cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];
cropNode.name = @"cropNode";
cropNode.position = CGPointZero;
cropNode.zPosition = 2;
[cropNode setMaskNode: node];
[cropNode addChild:mask];
[scene addChild:cropNode];
```

I am wondering if someone has successfully implemented the feature with similar approach above, if yes, please clarify it a little bit, if not, can you post your solution? thanks a lot.

I attached a Picture to show the same code running on Simulator and a iPhone 6:
[Picture to show the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHWzG.jpg)

My plan:

Instead of using SKCropNode, I will programmatically create a UIImage with a hole at the right position and render it as a texture of a SKSpriteNode. I have implemented the feature by init a SKSpriteNode with the created UIImage:

```
-(instancetype)init{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGRect spotLightRect = CGRectMake(100,100,200,200); // adjust this as desired!
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor*bColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, bColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect); //the mask
    UIColor*aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, aColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(c, spotLightRect); //the hole
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    SKTexture* texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
    self = [super initWithTexture:texture];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: why is your mask alpha 0.5?

Answer (score 1):

You are having problems with your position and math, I am going to break it down

Leave:

```
SKSpriteNode* mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:size];
```

remove:

```
mask.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
```

leave:

```
mask.name = @"Mask";
mask.alpha = 0.5;
```

remove:

```
mask.zPosition = 3;
```

leave:

```
SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:size];
```

remove:

```
node.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
```

leave:

```
node.name = @"circleMask";
```

remove:

```
node.zPosition = 1;
```

leave:

```
node.alpha = 1;
SKShapeNode* circleNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:100/2 + 20];
circleNode.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
circleNode.lineWidth = 0;
circleNode.alpha = 1;
circleNode.position = CGPointMake(80, -200);
circleNode.name = @"circleNode";
```

remove:

```
circleNode.zPosition = 1;
```

leave:

```
circleNode.blendMode = SKBlendModeSubtract;
[node addChild:circleNode];

SKCropNode* cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];
cropNode.name = @"cropNode";
cropNode.position = CGPointZero;
cropNode.zPosition = 2;
[cropNode setMaskNode: node];
[cropNode addChild:mask];
[scene addChild:cropNode];
```

Final result:

```
SKSpriteNode* mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:size];
mask.name = @"Mask";
mask.alpha = 0.5;

SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:size];
node.name = @"circleMask";
node.alpha = 1;
SKShapeNode* circleNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:100/2+20];
circleNode.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
circleNode.lineWidth = 0;
circleNode.alpha = 1;
circleNode.position = CGPointMake(80, -200);
circleNode.name = @"circleNode";
circleNode.blendMode = SKBlendModeSubtract;
[node addChild:circleNode];

SKCropNode* cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];
cropNode.name = @"cropNode";
cropNode.position = CGPointZero;
cropNode.zPosition = 2;
[cropNode setMaskNode: node];
[cropNode addChild:mask];
[scene addChild:cropNode];
```

You should now have a black screen with a hole at 80,-200

Comment: @KnightOfDragon thank you very much for your prompt reply. I tried your final sample code, unfortunately, it can't not make a hole on real device, I tested on iPhone 6, iPhone 5s, iPhone 7 with IOS 10, 11. But it do work on all Simulators. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: what method are you doing this in?

Comment: I just created a very simple SK project with only your code in. only have a SKView, a SKScene, and a SKSpriteNode. but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not very sure what is your question for, I just put it in viewDidLoad in my ViewController where I initialized a SKView , a SKScene and a SKSpriteNode.